# Logs are not coming in logDNA Console

Tags: ibm-cloud, logdna

I have configured lite version of logDNA in IBM cloud,
but whenever I am sending logs using curl command logs are not getting captured,
Although HOST is coming in `All Sources` and in `All Apps` I am getting `myapp`.

Here is my curl command

```
curl "https://logs.au-syd.logging.cloud.ibm.com/logs/ingest?hostname=EXAMPLE_HOST&mac=C0:FF:EE:C0:FF:EE&ip=10.0.1.101&now=$(date +%s)" \
-u INGETION_KEY: \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
-d \
'{
   "lines": [
     {
       "line":"This is an my log line",
       "app":"myapp",
       "level": "INFO",
       "env": "DEV",
       "meta": {
         "customfield": {
           "nestedfield": "nestedvalue"
         }
       }
     }
   ]
}'
```

After posting this curl command from my system I am getting this response back

```
{"status":"ok","batchID":"a9fc7347-e4ef-42f7-9241-63291911cee6:20274:ld62"}%
```

Any Help would be appriciated

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you whitelist your domain in the LogDNA settings?

Also, the LogDNA lite version on IBM Cloud only has live tail and does not store any logs.  It can be easy to miss the logs if you refresh the browser.

Comment: Thanks @kouichi after whitelisting the domain name I can see the logs,

Comment: I have the same problem. Where in IBM Cloud I can whitelist my domain? I am unable to find the LogDNA settings page. TIA

Comment: @Shashi after logging into your Log Analysis Observability instance, go to Settings >> Organization >> CORD Origins to whitelist a domain.  Or you can just use a link like this after changing to the correct IBM region:  https://app.us-south.logging.cloud.ibm.com/manage/cors-origins